# Free incident management tool for more than 50 users

Tags: gratis, web-apps, project-management, multi-user

In our DevOps team (~10) we get a few bug reports, change requests or incident reports per week. These modest volumes don't merit an application like TopDesk, so I wondered if someone knows of a good (and free) incident management tool. A search on Google didn't yield any interesting results, but maybe I was using the wrong keywords.

## Requirements

- Creation of tickets
- Ticket categorization
- Ticket prioritization
- Comments on tickets
- Ticket tracking
- Gratis

## Environment

- User > 50
- Server should run on Linux (but Windows suggestions are accepted)
- Client should be a web-app

Comment: Would you like that it works as web interface? You said  you have experience with TopDesk, what characteristics you liked/disliked of TopDesk?

Comment: @Braiam I like TopDesk, but it's too expensive for our modest needs.

Comment: Talking about "DevOps": I'd have some system in mind which covers all your requirements IMHO (I'm using it myself), but would go far beyond (Wiki, source code, tickets, and more, with the possibility to link between all these components). Works web-based (interaction via web browser), runs a.o. on Linux. Would that be acceptable, or too heavy?

Comment: Being a long-time [Mantis](http://mantisbt.org) user, we just tried [Trello](http://trello.com) for a smaller project to document a testing phase. While not the most "classic" tool, I still think it _might_ be something that could help you, too.

Comment: Mantis is a nifty tool, and quite versatile at that.

Answer (score 26):

I'm a long-time user of **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)**. It's a Python based client-server application, which means you run it on the server, and the "clients" need nothing but a web browser to access it:

[image: Trac example] [image: TracDroid] [image: Trac Client]
<sup>Example screenshot from one of my projects / Android clients (click images for larger variants)</sup>

It certainly matches your requirements:

- *Creation of tickets:* Sure. That's its main purpose.
- *Ticket categorization:* As the screenshot shows, in multiple ways: by component, ticket type, and more
- *Ticket prioritization:* Yepp (the screenshot indicates this by background colors: the cyan ones are low prio)
- *Comments on tickets:* Definitly. Even attachments are possible.
- *Ticket tracking:* Sure. Everybody involved can even get a mail sent when anything happens (new comment, ticket state changes, etc.)
- *Gratis:* Not only that, even [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source).
- *User > 50:* Let me count... My installation currently counts 203, so: *check* :)
- *Server should run on Linux:* That it does here (currently on Debian)
- *Client should be a web-app:* Yes. Just the browser is enough, so not even an additional installation required on the user's end. But if you insist, there are also [alternative clients](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Clients) available ­– even for mobile devices, e.g. [TracDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.suwes.TracDroid.free) or [Trac Client](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.mfvl.trac.client) on Android.

For a short intro, you might also wish to check the [Trac article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac).

While fully matching your requirements, *Trac* can do much more out-of-the-box: it contains a Wiki, and support for version control systems (source code). And you can cross-link between the components, to e.g. address a ticket in a SVN commit, or a revision in the ticket ("This is solved with revision:123"), or both from the Wiki, or... Well, you could also extend the functionality with one of the hundreds of addons available at [Trac-Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/).

Of course, the [project site](http://trac.edgewall.org/) itself as well as [Tac-Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) are running *Trac*, so if you want to see a real live demo, just head there.

Comment: Can Trac create tickets that are sent to support@company.com ?

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear or to user@example.com – up to you which email address you define for the project owner :)

Comment: No, I meant Tracto be set up and configured so to have an incoming email support@company.com for issues to be mailed in. Then somebody with an issue writes to support@company.com with the issue, and then the Trac system creates a ticket automatically with the issue desribed in the email.

Or did you mean Trac can have support@company.com or user@example.com as incoming email to automatically create tickets?

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear AFAIR this is possible – either directly or with one of the many plugins. I've never used that feature, and stopped using Trac as well a few years ago.

Answer (score 10):

A few years back, I've tried [**Redmine**](http://www.redmine.org/) and it could be an option for you.

### Requirements

[image: Yes] You can create tickets, they are called issues in this environment 
[image: Yes] Categorization of issues is possible 
[image: Yes] Priorities for issues can be set, too 
[image: Yes] Every issue can be discussed by adding comments 
[image: Yes] Issue tracking is integrated (for example by subscribing to an issue specific RSS  feed) 
[image: Yes] It's open source and free

### Environment

[image: Yes] [More than 50 users should be possible](http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/25331), although I haven't tried it myself.  
[image: Yes] Server side runs on Windows, Unix, Linux and Mac 
[image: Yes] Clients use a browser to access the tool.

There's an online demo available: http://demo.redmine.org/

Answer (score 6):

#### Mantis Bug Tracker

I would suggest [Mantis](http://mantisbt.org/) as few commenters already did. I'm using it successfully. It is:

- free
- open source – GPL
- well-customizable just by configuration (workflows, statuses, categories, priorities)
- mobile access addon (3rd-party, not free)
- e-mail integration – creation of tickets from e-mails

Requirements:

- PHP

Mantis is a great starter for individuals and small companies because standard PHP hosting is currently more accessible (and cheaper) than other options. For example many standard web providers don't support Python or ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the [SiT! Support Incident Tracker](http://sitracker.org/) (and actually [compared it to other solutions](http://www.slideshare.net/NicolasRaoul/helpdesk-software-comparizon-matrix)).

It fulfils all of your listed requirements.

[image]

### Requirements

[image: Yes] You can create tickets
[image: Yes] Categorization is made with [skills](http://sitracker.org/wiki/Skills), [products](http://sitracker.org/wiki/Products) and sites 
[image: Yes] Priorities for issues can be chosen 
[image: Yes] You can add comments and see the history of the incident 
[image: Yes] Ticket tracking is possible 
[image: Yes] It's open source and free

### Environment

[image: Yes] Supports more than 50 users 
[image: Yes] Server side runs on Windows, Unix, Linux and Mac 
[image: Yes] Client is a webapp.

Comment: Can SiT! automatically create tickets if somebody mails support@company.com with an issue?

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear: I guess but please ask at http://superuser.com to be sure and know how. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Customizer's suggestion of Redmine. Our team has been using it for years and it's worked out great for us.

Just so you know, you can go to [Digital Ocean](https://m.do.co/c/3d1c2b016a00) and quickly spin up Redmine with their one-click install. Might be quicker than installing on your own server for testing.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Eventum](https://launchpad.net/eventum) for both customer support tickets and development issue tracking.

Requirements:

- Creation of tickets - a click away
- Ticket categorization - check
- Ticket prioritization - check
- Comments on tickets - set it initially, editable afterwards
- Ticket tracking - check
- Gratis - check

Environment:

- User > 50 - no problem
- Server should run on Linux (but Windows suggestions are accepted) - Linux; requires MySQL and PHP, so it is quite easy to customize
- Client should be a web-app - I added a few screenshots for your convenience:

[image: General image view]

[image]

[image]

Here's a short presentation: [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/joaopmaia/eventum-presentation).

Accolades: "Eventum is used by the MySQL AB Technical Support team, and has allowed us to dramatically improve our response times."

Comment: Does Eventum have the ability to automatically create tickets if someboy were to mail support@company.com?

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear This comes as a surprise for me, it *seems* to support what you're looking for: https://github.com/eventum/eventum/wiki/Basic-User:-Creating-Issues .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **GitLab**. It fulfils all your requirements, it's open-source, and the platform that it's a basis of is a leading competitor to GitHub. You may either use that platform for free or self-host.