# What's a good all-in-one support portal/knowledge base/wiki for a SMB?

Tags: knowledge-base, support-tracker

I think we've finally convinced `$company` that a ticket system, a knowledge base, and an internal IT wiki are all good ideas. The challenging part is that there's no way we'll maintain all three separately, as documentation is already sparse and a ticket system will be a huge adjustment in the first place.

I'm looking for a software solution that will basically do all three. I'm hoping to:

- Create support tickets (nothing fancy needed, just a 'halp plz!!' inbox)
- Create a private IT wiki
- Create a knowledge base that users can look at

The idea is to take tickets and turn it in to a wiki. We only have a couple hundred users, so there's really no need for too many bells and whistles. We do some inhouse development as well, so generating a sort-of 'manual' for our LOB app would be good.

Free/not free, SaaS/server doesn't really matter. We are a Windows shop though, so spinning up something on a Linux box might be a tough sell.

Any suggestions?

**Note**: No need for version control or file repository. All of this will be internal.

Comment: Definitly! Check my answer here: [Free incident management tool for more than 50 users](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185#1560). *Trac* covers all that, and more.

Comment: Two products, but from one hand and well integrated: JIRA + Confluence.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Bloodhound may do the trick for you.

[Bloodhound Website](http://bloodhound.apache.org/)

It meets all your criteria, and its open source.
Now to temper this answer I have not used Bloodhound personally, I can't attest to how well it works.

If you have the funding, support and initiative right now I would consider going and getting a tool that meets your current requirements and provides more.  A content management/collaboration suite can do what you are looking for...and a whole lot more.  Things like [SharePoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/) or [Huddle](https://www.huddle.com/) can manage ticketing, come with built in and custom workflows, they can serve as front ends for (and host) databases, and the wiki creation/management is very easy, and frankly thats the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Sirportly](http://sirportly.com/features)? (Note: this answer is customised for your post but similar to my answer here: [Help Desk Software?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/help-desk-software/1805#1805))

**Features from your list**

- it **accepts tickets** via email or webform
- it has **knowledge bases**, that can be public or private, or a mix of both
- It **can be self-hosted or SaaS** - although if self hosted, you'd need a Linux server.

**Bonus stuff**

- supports multiple brands, departments, custom ticket statuses and tags for easy filtering, and easy **multiple queue management**
- can be **integrated with mail clients** for notification, and there is also a custom desktop notification app that's cross platform
- there is also a **free 3-user account** for the web non self hosted version, which you could try out to see if it was worth purchasing.

**My experience with it**

- I used it mostly from an administrator's point of view, setting up queues and providing support for the users. I could save custom queues, manage users, create form responses, and generally configure it to my needs.
- the devs at sirportly are *amazingly responsive*. Whenever we had comments or bugs they'd do their best to help out.
- we got hundreds or thousands of customer mails per day - before using Sirportly, most of our staff had average of 10gb .pst files. Sirportly handled the scale just fine.

If I ever have to find a help desk solution for a different company in the future, I'd absolutely go with Sirportly again.