# Technical-Documentation, Knowledge base, Help-Desk

Tags: document-management, documentation-generator, knowledge-base, help-desk, documentation

We are building help-desk/knowledge base for an electron based software. Need recommendations for some platforms that support the following specifications ;

1. The platform should be able to store the technical documentation of our software and its meta data.
2. Platform should provide Offline and online support for help-desk/knowledge so built.
3. Platform should provide in-app overlay for some contents that will guide the user through.
4. For some specific text contents it should support including an embedded video to explain that text content.
5. It should support search bar navigation for contents of.

Comment: I think that you need to define your requirements further.  These are just too broad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help Desk Software?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/help-desk-software)

Comment: @AaronLiu I am looking for a platform to build help desk that stores the technical documentation of our software. This link provides different software that can be used for customer service.