# Which simple project management software running on our own intranet server allows time tracking?

Tags: project-management, intranet

I'm looking for a simple project management software that can be installed on our own server and allows time tracking.

The features I need are as follows:

- support for several projects
- support for several users (10-20)
- support for several tasks per project
- time tracking, i.e. how much time was spent on each task and how much time was estimated beforehand, and ability to add some comment on a task (e.g. why it did take longer)
- web interface would be an advantage (since we have Macs and Windows machines)
- Outlook integration would be an advantage, but is not necessary
- simple overview and maybe warnings if some task is not in budget
- a software that can be installed on our server, i.e. no SAAS, cloud based solution

I don't need to upload files, email, GANTT charts, chat, wiki and the other stuff. The team is all on site and uses other tools for file exchange, mail etc.

It should be only really simple to enter the time one spent on a task since this is by far the most common task and done by most people.

The product hasn't to be free but should not be too expensive - a monthly fee or initial costs of more than 1000€ will definitely be a show-stopper.

I would be grateful if you could provide me some recommendations since I have found no solution that allows all of that.

Comment: I have used [TRAC](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for this for many years using the [Timing and Estimation Plugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimingAndEstimationPlugin), but since the main focus is elsewhere this might not be the best solution for you.

Comment: On *Trac*, also see my answer here: [Free incident management tool for more than 50 users](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185#1560). I use it for multiple projects (see the drop-down in the upper right corner of the first screenshot there, which switches between projects). Looks like a good match, I don't see any of your requirements which couldn't be met (if needed, by a plugin).

Comment: @Izzy: I don't know how much it improved in the couple of years since I last used it, but back when we did the timing and estimation was not capable of any planning. It could show gantt chart, but you had to set all the dates by hand.

Comment: As I'm not using Gantt, I cannot argue about that. Using Trac since 0.8, for me it does what I need (and what I missed, I added myself (it's open source), and made it available on TracHacks (e.g. LogViewer).

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer**: I am developer of this software.

I would recommend Eylean board as it is on premises deployed client-server application. It has integrated time tracking. Integration to outlook and excel alongside TFS sync. for developers. 
It fits any agile process due to vast feature selection.

[www.eylean.com](http://www.eylean.com)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try Merlin 2**
- With Merlin for OS X you have the software that gives you all needed tools to successfully implement projects on time and budget. Merlin is intuitive, easy to use and offers the widest variety of exchange formats in a project management software.

- Merlin Server delivers the ultimate network landscape for enabling professional project management. Merlin Server redefines true ease of use by delivering no less than three built-in network services in the form of a System Preference. Not only can all projects be published for Merlin on Mac OS X, including access for web browsers and iPhones, but these services are always accessible and built right into Mac OS X.
  The Web Service delivered with Merlin Server allows one to work on published projects across an intranet or internet using a supported web browser.* This means Windows users not having Merlin can easily access and work on Merlin projects!

Support: Comprehensive documentation, free and unlimited e-mail support, YouTube videos, user forums and social media channels.

At the moment we offer a "Server Bundle" - http://projectwizards.net/en/products/?f=bundle

And fell free to test or software for free (and time unlimited)

Best regards Michael

Comment: We have Windows servers, so this is no option I suppose?

Answer (score -2):

I work for Twproject that is a web based project management system that can be installed on your server (any server) and use your preferred DB.
You have no limit on the number of project.
Every project can be structured in several sub-task, sub-sub-task and so on (you can define you WBS with a js Gantt editor).

Time tracking is immediate and can be done in several ways: weekly, daily, using start/stop buttons, directly on project, tasks, when closing issues and so on.

I think the nicer feature of Twproject is that id adapts to your working-style, reducing the impact on your team.

Receiving alerts for overflow budget or work overflow is almost automatic (but eventually also when a milestone is approaching or you miss a dead-line).

Of course it has several additional features (issues, documents, full text indexing, shared Agenda, reminders, customization, workflow, kanban  and much more), but in my experience the better results are obtained when you start with eventually a reduced requirement coverage, but with a massive usage: is better to have use 70% of the software instead of have 70% of time recorder :-)