# Ticket tracking project management workflow software

Tags: project-management, version-control, workflow, issue-tracker

I'm looking for a piece of software that fulfills the following requirements. I've exhausted my search capabilities.

- Version control integration (SVN preferred)
- Tickets support custom fields, including search and filter
- Different types of tickets can go through different custom workflows
- Support of multiple projects
- User access controlled by roles assigned permissions per project and/or per workflow
- Gantt chart
- Time tracking aggregated by state in workflow per ticket, or generic 'activity' on ticket
- View, Edit permissions per field, per role, per state in workflow
- Ability to set whether a field is required per state in workflow
- Release / burndown management
- Continuous Integration integration (Maven preferred)
- Eclipse / Mylyn Integration
- Hard coded start / due dates, and expected start / finish dates based on resource availability (Nice to have)
- Resource leveling (Nice to have)
- What if scenarios - What would happen to the dates of Project A if I prioritized Project B (Nice to have)
- Active Directory integration (Nice to have)

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) was really close, but the lack of ability to set permissions per project / workflow (tracker) is a show stopper.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)** for this kind of job (see [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185) for details):

- *Version control integration (SVN preferred):* Definitely. I'm using it with SVN, but other VCSs (e.g. git) are also supported.
- *Tickets support custom fields, including search and filter:* Yes. And more, like master tickets/dependencies, tags, ...
- *Different types of tickets can go through different custom workflows:* Custom workflows are possible. AFAIK this should be doable, though I've not explicitly verified the "different tickets use different workflows" part.
- *Support of multiple projects:* I'm running it this way. For easy switching between them from the web frontend, there's a plugin available.
- *User access controlled by roles assigned permissions per project and/or per workflow:* Per project definitively. Per workflow probably not, but there might be a solution for that as well.
- *Gantt chart:* via plugin, yes.
- *Time tracking aggregated by state in workflow per ticket, or generic 'activity' on ticket:* Again via a specific plugin, yes.
- *View, Edit permissions per field, per role, per state in workflow:* Not sure what you mean here, but as everything is highly customizable, let's agree on a "maybe" :)
- *Ability to set whether a field is required per state in workflow:* If I remember correctly, there was a way to define required/optional fields.
- *Release / burndown management:* Yes, via the Burndown plugin
- *Continuous Integration integration (Maven preferred):* Here I'm not sure, but I think I've seen a plugin for that as well.

For the other requirements, I'm not 100% sure. But as *Trac* is open source (it's written in Python), you can always add what you're missing. I did that myself a couple of times (I wrote e.g. the LogViewer Plugin, and integrated *Trac* with my local environment to do a lot of things via scripts). It's definitely worth a look.

As I've mentioned the plugins that often: Many of them are available via the [Tac-Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) site. Basically, *Trac* itself provides a solid core, and then you can customize it via plugins the way you need it.