# A tool to visualize the build pipeline from issues all the way through to releases

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm looking for a tool, maybe even just a read only web based dashboard that I can use to visually represent the components involved in getting a raised issue (bug, feature, etc) in an issue tracker into release. Ideally, it would include support for...

- Issue Trackers (eg: BugZilla)
- Source repositories (eg: GitHub)
- CI server jobs (eg: Jenkins)
- Artefact store (eg: Artifactory)

The view could show;

```
[issue:#123] -> [Git branch origin/bug#123] -> [build: failing] -> [null]
[issue:#456] -> [Git branch origin/bug#456] -> [build: passed] -> [file "release.1.0.exe"]
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, ***Trac*** should be able to do that with the appropriate plugins (see my answers [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185#1560) and [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7492/185#7501) for general details). It includes a bug-tracker (and a wiki, and much more), supports Git (and SVN, and more) – but I cannot speak for the other two. I'm using *Trac* for years, but never had this specific requirement – hence I cannot say for sure, and hence a comment instead of an answer ;)