# Open source project management software

Tags: open-source, web-apps, project-management, git

I need a web based project management software. It should basically have:

- Issue tracker
- Wiki (not mandatory)
- Git integration
- Progress

It should be open source and I should be able to install it onto my server.

Currently, I have found the following options :

- [ProjeQtOr](http://www.projeqtor.org/)
- [MyCollab](http://community.mycollab.com/)

Is there anyone who tested one of those software? I'm also open to any other suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)** (for details and screenshots, see my answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7501/185) and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185). Trac fulfills all your requirements listed:

- **Issue tracker:** Yes.
- **Wiki:** Yes.
- **GIT integration:** Yes, also other VCSs as e.g. SVN or Mercurial are supported. For Git, there's even integration with Github.
- **Progress:** Yes, via multiple plugins you can even chose what fits you best.
- **Self-hosted:** Definitely, that's what I use. Requirements are at least Python and a web server supporting Python; setup is not that difficult using Apache.

A setup [guide for use with SVN can be found on my server](http://www.izzysoft.de/software/ifaqmaker.php?id=1). You can skip the SVN part and take a look at [Installing Trac](http://www.izzysoft.de/software/ifaqmaker.php?id=1;toc=1;topic=trac_install) and [Useful Trac resources](http://www.izzysoft.de/software/ifaqmaker.php?id=1;toc=1;topic=trac_resources). I'm sure there are guides for setting up Trac with Git as well, and probably even more up-to-date ones at that (mine is already a little outdated).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some people recommend RedMine over Trac. Have you also tried RedMine?

Comment: No. I'm using *Trac* for years already (since v0.8), and until now never saw a reason to look for something different.

Comment: Enjoy! For performance reasons, I recommend to not use mod_python but [mod_wsgi](http://www.modwsgi.org/) – gives a huge speedup.

Answer (score 2):

There are various options out there: Gitlab, Redmine, Launchpad, and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software).

Out of all of these, I have the best experience with **GitLab**, which is used by the likes of the **GNOME project and F-Droid**. (According to Wikipedia, other users include  IBM, Sony, Jülich Research Center, NASA, Alibaba, Invincea, O’Reilly Media, Leibniz-Rechenzentrum (LRZ), CERN, European XFEL, and SpaceX)

As for your needs:

- Issue tracker: yes
- Wiki (not mandatory): yes
- Git integration: yes
- Progress: I think so--see if [milestones](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/milestones/) meet your needs
- Open-source: yes
- Can self-host: yes