# A tool for illustrating SVN repo trees?

Tags: diagram, subversion

My team uses five separate SVN repositories, for five different modules or apps that we're maintaining. Each one has its own version sequence.

We like to **have a "wall poster" of the current state of our repos** with their branches. Currently, we're using a whiteboard for this, and it works well enough. But I'm wondering **whether a tool exists** that can help us with this? I'd be fine with having to manually update a document (Visio or whatever) but bonus points for a tool that can pull automatically from our SVN server of course.

**Our whiteboard looks roughly like this:** 
We have a main development line in the trunk `===`. When a release is complete, we tag it `o` and create a maintenance branch `---` so that we can deliver bugfix release tags `o` while trunk development continues.

```
Foo trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Foo 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Foo 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

Bar trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Bar 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Bar 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

Xyz trunk:   o===dev1.0===o====dev1.1===========o====dev1.2==========
Xyz 1.0.x maintenance:    |---fix1.0.1--o---    |
Xyz 1.1.x maintenance:                          |--fix1.1.1--o---

...
```

Is there a tool that could help maintain a "poster" that looks similar to this? Note that I want to make this for several repos on a server, not just for a single repo, and that I only care about the **tags** and not about the individual checkins.

Comment: Not sure if it exactly fits, but [*Trac*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13383/185#13391) has some addons for that using Graphviz to automatically visualize repos. Not sure if that could be configured to make exactly the trees you're after, but it's certainly worth a look. See e.g. its [Revtree plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/RevtreePlugin) (page has screenshots).

Comment: Not an answer, as you are already using SVN and presumably stuck with it, but that is the reason that I switched our small company from SVN to Plastic SCM . "The branch explorer was created after the typical blackboard diagram that every team draws when they try to explain the merge structure of the project" - http://plasticscm.com/branch-explorer/index.html   Perhaps this might help others who find this question and are either in a position to switch or or looking for a new VCS ... http://plasticscm.com/branch-explorer/assets/img/branch-explorer-illustration.png

Answer (score 6):

## [TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/)

TikZ is a (La)TeX package for drawing all sorts of diagrams. I use it for most of my drawing needs. Its features include:

- Intuitive language syntax
- Vector graphics (so you could scale your poster to any size),
- A huge selection of libraries,
- Ability to define custom commands and styles
- A [detailed user manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf),
- Excellent community support on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) (most popular question tag over there with nearly 9000 questions).

Here is an example of the first part of your diagram as drawn with TikZ:

[image]

---

Source code for above diagram:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}
\tikzstyle{revision}=[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{trunkline}=[draw,ultra thick,postaction={draw,thick,color=white}]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm]
  \node[minimum width=4cm] (footrunk) {Foo trunk:};
  \node[revision,right= of footrunk,right=5mm,fill=gray!60] (rev12345) {};
  \node[revision,right= of rev12345] (rev12346) {};
  \node[revision,right= of rev12346,right=3cm] (rev12347) {};
  \node[revision,right= of rev12347] (rev12348) {};

  \node[minimum width=4cm,below= of footrunk,above] (maintenance1) {Foo 1.0.x maintenance};
  \node[revision,below=of rev12346,above] (fix10) {};
  \node[revision,right=of fix10] (fix101) {};
  \node[minimum width=4cm,below= of maintenance1,above] (maintenance2) {Foo 1.1.x maintenance};
  \node[revision,node distance=2cm,below=of rev12347,above] (fix11) {};
  \node[revision,right=of fix11] (fix111) {};

  \draw[trunkline] (rev12345) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{dev1.0} (rev12346);
  \draw[trunkline] (rev12346) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{dev1.1} (rev12347);
  \draw[trunkline] (rev12347) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{dev1.2} (rev12348);
  \draw[very thick,dotted,-stealth'] (rev12348) -- ++(1cm,0);
  \draw (rev12346) -- (fix10);
  \draw (fix10) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{fix1.0.1} (fix101);
  \draw[thick,blue,dashed,-stealth'] (fix101) -- (rev12347);
  \draw (rev12347) -- (fix11);
  \draw (fix11) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{fix1.1.1} (fix111);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

## Edit concerning automation

To automate these diagrams, you'll have to make use of the macros in the TikZ package. Since performing mathematical operations in TikZ is still a pain, it's even better if you could use another powerful language to edit the `tex` file, like Perl or Python. These can also be used to extract data from your SVN log files, achieving a fully automated process.

Here is an attempt to automate the above diagram using TikZ alone with 3 input variables: First and last revs, and number of branches. Of course, this works only for this specific form of trees, but it'll serve as an example on how macros work.

**main script**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows}

% Macros
\input{svn_macros}
% Configuration
\newcommand\FirstRevNumber{12345}
\newcommand\CurrentRevNumber{12348}
\newcommand\FixCount{2}
% End of configuration

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1.5cm]
  \node[minimum width=4cm] (0) {Foo trunk:};
  \firstrevision{\FirstRevNumber}{0}
  \foreach \rev [count=\counter from 0]  in {\FirstRevNumber,...,\CurrentRevNumber}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextRev}{\rev+1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\FixNum}{\counter+1}
    \revision{\NextRev}{\rev}\mainline{\rev}{\NextRev}{dev1.\counter}
    \ifnum\counter<\FixCount
      \node[minimum width=4cm,below= of \counter,above] (\FixNum) {Foo 1.\counter.x maintenance};
      \newfix[\FixNum]{1\counter}{\NextRev}
      \fix{1\counter1}{1\counter}
      \branchline{1\counter}{1\counter1}{fix1.\counter.1}
    \fi
  }
  \foreach \rev [count=\counter from 0]  in {\FirstRevNumber,...,\CurrentRevNumber}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\SecondNextRev}{\rev+2}
    \ifnum\counter<\FixCount
      \draw[thick,blue,dashed,-stealth'] (1\counter1) -- (\SecondNextRev);
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**imported file**

```
\newcommand\firstrevision[2]{\node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,right= of #2,right=5mm,fill=gray!60](#1){};}
\newcommand\revision[2]{\node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,right= of #2,right=2cm](#1){};}
\newcommand\newfix[3][1]{\node[draw,circle,node distance=#1cm,inner sep=2pt,below= of #3,above](#2){};\draw (#3) -- (#2);}
\newcommand\fix[2]{\node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,right= of #2](#1){};}
\newcommand\mainline[3]{\draw[ultra thick,postaction={draw,thick,color=white}] (#1) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{#3} (#2);}
\newcommand\branchline[3]{\draw (#1) -- node[font=\scriptsize,fill=white]{#3} (#2);}
```

This would produce a similar tree to the above figure, but if you increase the numbers in the *Configuration* section (12345, 12360, and 8, for example), you could end up with a pretty long tree:

**Result**

[image]

(Click image for bigger version)

Comment: Thank you, recreating my diagram certainly demonstrates how well your suggestion works. It seems very structured -- now, if there'd be a way to generate this automatically, it would be _perfect._

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I'd say it's quite possible, but definitely not something one could whip up during a lengthy coffee break. Given enough time, one could define a series of macros in TeX to form a pattern of the diagrams, then write a script in a powerful programming language such as Perl or  Python. It would read the data from your SVN log file and generate the corresponding picture. Maybe if you could post a sample log file that corresponds to the posted diagram, and I'll try to post an example script to read that

Comment: Yeah, some kind of SVN file parsing is required. I'm not giving you a logfile - not because of secrecy but because I'd rather not you spend time working out a script that I could probably get into actual operation at work.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I edited the answer with another example that contains macros. I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, there was a word from my last comment! I meant: *because I'd rather not you spend time working out a script that I could probably **not** get into actual operation at work.*

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun No harm done :). It's a great question, and there are probably better and easier tools out there

Answer (score 0):

Since you are likely to wish/need to do this several times a week and svn log operations are often time consuming I would suggest having [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) local repositories of the SVN repositories, (using [hgsubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion)), to speed things up.

Mercurial also has some very sophisticated log output facilities, (see `hg help log` and `hg help templates` for more details), that you could probably use to produce output that would be easily massaged into something like [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to give your graph.