# Most appropriate software for data warehouse ticket tracker and encyclopedia

Tags: database, cms, wiki

My university is working on a data warehouse and I was given a task to create a website (we call it "data warehouse encyclopedia, but it isn´t a widely used title"), which will have few simple purposes:

**Ticket tracker** - Someone (teacher, dean.. very likely doesn´t know much about IT) would like a report. So he makes a ticket "I would like some charts and tables about this". All tickets will be requests for report.

**Report archive** - Someone recieves a ticket, creates and saves appropriate report. Tags for searching would be useful here.

**Dictionary** - Something like wikipedia, basic definitions, maybe some how-to.

That's pretty much all. It has to be free software, but I don't need anything fancy with many features, just basic and simple functionality.

So my main question is - Which CMS/wiki/issue tracker would be the best choice for these requirements? Unfortunately, I have never worked with any, so I have no idea, how appropriate would any software be. I did a little research and found few candidates:

Redmine - looks like a good choice

Wordpress/Drupal/Joomla - with plugins (would you recommend any specific plugins for my task?)

Tiki Wiki CMS/Trac/Freedcamp/Dokuwiki - not sure if these are any good, but I found them while searching for alternatives.

Could anyone recommend any of mentioned software or add any additional info? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to combine a "ticket tracker" with a "wiki", **Trac** should be worth a look – as you can even cross-reference between the two (e.g. "see ticket:3" in wiki, or "see [WikiPage]" in a ticket). For details, see my answers [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13391/185) and [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185). Web based, and there are even several (Android) apps supporting it. Extensible with a load of plugins in case you miss something :)

Comment: Yes Trac is amazing when it come to ticket + wiki

Comment: Thanks! I'll try Trac as soon as possible!

Comment: @Izzy: Maybe you could write an answer? :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul enforcing my rep today, are you? :) Done.

Comment: "free software" as in [*Freeware*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware) or as in [*Free software*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)? And I assume you want to host the website yourself, correct?

Comment: So I eventually chose Redmine, but Trac would be a very good choice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually chose Redmine and it matched my requirements, but Trac would be a very good choice, too.

I used ticket tracking for creating and keeping report requests.
"Documents" section of redmine for finished reports
"Wiki" for dictionary (business and technical metadata)

I tried Asana and Wordpress and they weren't useful for me, Openproject is basically better looking redmine without the plugins.

Comment: Would you mind adding a few lines on how it matched your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Following up Nicolas' wish:</sup>

As described e.g. in [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185) (and some of the questions linked to it) and [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13391/185), **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)** might be a good candidate. It not only combines a "ticket tracker" with a "wiki" (plus a "source code repository"), which can be cross-linked (e.g. you can write something like "this problem is already addressed with ticket:15" in the wiki, and the ticket will be linked automatically) – but there are tons of plugins<sup>1</sup> you can use to extend its features, making it better suit your requirements.

*Trac* is open-source, written in Python (so you can even easily adjust it yourself with some Python knowledge), highly customizable, web-based (so you can access it from anywhere), and even has some supporting Android apps. Let's check it against your listed requirements:

- **Ticket tracker:** Yes. Extensible by plugins, e.g. for "MasterTickets" and ticket dependencies.
- **Report archive:** Yes. You even can create your own reports, and – using the appropriate plugins – add specific reporting features you need, e.g. [Gantt charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).
- **Tags:** Built-in tag system, again extensible by plugins
- **Dictionary:** Can be done, has been done. Either linking terms directly, or using "`<acronym>`s" (again, there's a specific plugin for that for easy handling – see [here](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AcronymDefinitions))
- **free software:** free as in beer, free as in speech: [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) (no cost), [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source).
- **just basic and simple functionality:** That's mostly like it ships. Due to its modular design, you then can add those features you need – without including too much "fancy with many features"

---

<sup>**1:** See [Trac-Hacks.ORG](https://www.trac-hacks.org/) (running *Trac* itself) and its [Git repo](https://github.com/rjollos/trachacks)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For a dictionary you could try [Ooluk Data Dictionary Manager](http://www.ooluk.com). It is free for 10 users with unlimited anonymous users.

*Disclosure: I work at this company.*