# Free online bug tracker / to-do listing for personal use

Tags: gratis, web-apps, project-management, issue-tracker

I'm a mobile app developer and I'm looking for a free online bug/issue tracker for use only by me.

At the moment I'm using a simple doc file to list all `closed`, `in progress`, `resolved` etc... issues and to list all my new `features` and `to-dos`.

I'd like to use a tool for that in order to have a better management of the progresses during development.

The features I would need are:

- Possibility to choose the type of the case: `bug`, `feature`, `inquiry`, `schedule item` or others
- Possibility to create `subissues` or `categories`.
- Would be nice to have a `to-dos` section.
- It is enough that it works only for the admin of the project because I want to use it just for me and not with other team members or users.
- Possibility to add `tags` and click on those to filter all issues with that particular `tag`.
- free and available online

I have already tried:

- Redmine
- Trello
- Yodiz
- FogBugz

but they don't have all features I need.

I also know that there are tools like Bugzilla, JIRA etc., but I need a free and online tool so they are not good for me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is a self-hosted tool OK for you, if it matches all given criteria – and could do even more (e.g. allow you to browse your code, link from commits to the corresponding bug, allow other developers to join in if you decide so)?

Comment: I prefer not self-hosted, but I'm also thinking about that because they have more features. What do you suggest?

Comment: [Comparison of issue-tracking systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in) which is a complete source code management, issue tracker and wiki. Although this is slightly more than you wanted, the issue tracker covers everything you need.

It supports:

- Unlimited free private projects (maximum 10GB per project)
- Fully hosted
- Tagging issues (this can also be used to mark type of case)
- Filtering by tag
- Adding milestones to issues
- Referencing issues within other issues (usable for sub issues)
- To do lists in either issues or the wiki (each item has a checkbox next to it for marking if it is done or not)

Example of issue tracker (from public project of tortoise git):
[image]

Example of filtering by label(tag)[image]

Example of todo list
[image]

You can also host your version for free.

Comment: ok thanks that's good, but I'll wait for other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

With self-hosted at least being an option, I recommend taking a look at **[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)**. It can be run via e.g. Apache or Nginx, and is build using Python – fully open source, you can adjust it to your very needs.

#### Let's see how your requirements are met:

- **Possibility to choose the type of the case: bug, feature, inquiry, schedule item or others:** Some of these are already pre-configured, and you can easily define the others and more.
- **Possibility to create subissues or categories:** Yes, at least via plugins (there are tons of plugins for all kind of potential needs, see [TracHacks](https://trac-hacks.org/); this also includes ticket dependencies – e.g. if one issue blocks another)
- **Tagging issues (this can also be used to mark type of case):** Yes, out-of-the-box.
- **Filtering by tag :** Yes, out-of-the-box.
- **It is enough that it works only for the admin of the project because I want to use it just for me and not with other team members or users:** Just disable the account creation ("/register" URL), and you're the only user :)
- **Possibility to add tags and click on those to filter all issues with that particular tag:** Well, we've already had this with two separate items, so: Yes, out-of-the-box.

#### Additional features you might want (reading your question between the lines):

- support for many version-control-systems, such as Git, SVN, and more
- easily reference a bug from a commit and vice-versa, so you can see relations with a single click from each end
- integrated wiki, can be referenced the very same way with tickets and commits
- tons of plugins for whenever additional needs arise, e.g. to see your "project performance", using Gantt graphs, visualize commit history, and more

#### Related answers of mine showing more details on *Trac:*

- [Open source project management software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13391/185)
- [Ticket tracking project management workflow software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/7501/185)
- [Most appropriate software for data warehouse ticket tracker and encyclopedia](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17924/185)
- [https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185)

#### Screenshots from the last reference:

[image: Trac example] [image: TracDroid] [image: Trac Client]
<sup>Example screenshot from one of my projects / Android clients (click images for larger variants)</sup>