# Collaborative Web Based Wiki with ability to narrow down ideas by more than one metadata-tag?

Tags: search, wiki, metadata

Does a collaborative web-based wiki with the ability to narrow down wiki entries using more than one tag exist?

Let me give you an example of what I am looking for; the wiki has to have the following features:

1. Be accessed by multiple users with passwords concurrently.
2. Ability to tag wiki pages/content with multiple meta-data tags.
3. Have the ability to search the wiki using multiple tags to narrow down results in the wiki.

   - Here is a video with the [example functionality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtyv3lAsz60) that I'm looking for in a collaborative wiki; the wiki in the video is not multi-user.
   - Think twitter, if you type the `#red` and `#car` meta-data tags (hashtags) into the search box, you'll end up with all the tweets that have been tagged with both `#red` and `#car`.  If you type `#red #car #ford`, you'll get all the posts about red ford cars.

The reason this is so hard to find, is because many wiki's have HTML tags listed as a feature, and the semantics of tag overlap a bit that.

If you have an example wiki with the above stated functionality, can you also provide me with a link to the documentation about the stated feature?

Comment: Would MediaWiki be a possible answer? MediaWiki articles can have several categories.

Comment: Edgewall's project management software *Trac* includes a wiki matching your requirements (see [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21524/185) and the [Trac article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac)). Tagging and filtering included. Web based, written in Python, tons of plugins available. Though it's a project management software, you can decide to e.g. have all components disabled and just the Wiki active.