# Need a simple software to manage tasks and their prerequisites with graphical chart

Tags: windows, time-management

I need a software to manage my tasks. I cant use simple to do list soft wares because as far as I know they do not support prerequisite. of course I prefer to use a simple software, not a professional one like ms project. Would you please tell me what software should I use?
In another word, I have 20 tasks which some of them are prerequisites for another tasks. I want to have a graphical chart to see what is my way.
I'm using windows 7 and I prefer a software which have clients for android and web. but the main priority is a software to create a graph for me to know what to do now!

Comment: Just to clarify: you're talking about dependencies between tasks (e.g. "Task-3" requires that "Task-1" has been completed), right? And you need that for... what OS? Ya know, there might be some available on AmigaOS which are not available for Atari ;) (and btw, I've replaced your tag; `task-management` is for things like the Windows Task-Manager, i.e. about OS processes and the like, as the tag excerpt states).

Comment: @Izzy Man you know more than 90% of people are using windows, so take it Izzy ;)

Comment: I thought you were one of the other 10% using a real OS, sorry. And again: the `task-management` tag is for OS task management, so it doesn't fit your question ;)

Comment: @Izzy Do you have a usefull answer for me? Just name a software if you know plz

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, and also have no heavy needs for this kind of software – so no. The only context where I've used such a thing is managing tickets for bug reports/feature requests in software development, see [my answer here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185): *Trac* is capable of that (the feature is called "Master Tickets" and available as a plugin AFAIR). But I'm afraid that doesn't match your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Abstract Spoon's [ToDoList](https://www.abstractspoon.com/). It supports prerequisites and is also available Android & iOS. I generally use it from planning s/w projects, but ocassioanlly just for day to day ToDo stuff.

```
ToDoList's flexible design makes it ideal for both IT related projects  
as well as more general GTD uses.
```

Check out a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gv7ARrRTUhI).

[Download it from AbstractSpoon](https://www.abstractspoon.com/).

[image: Screenshot of ToDoList application]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like ToDoList and want something a bit more like MS Project, there are, of course, several (sucha s https://www.openproject.org/ which might be too much for your needs).

The best that I found when I tried them all a few months ago (before deciding to stick with ToDoList), was [TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/).

That one uses Gantt charts and has some impressive features:

Basic Properties

```
Manages tasks, resources and accounts of your project
Powerful to-do list management
Detailed reference manual
Simple installation
Runs on all Linux, Unix, Windows, MacOS and several other operating systems
Full integration with Vim text editor
```

Advanced Scheduling

```
Automatic resource leveling and tasks conflict resolution
Unlimited number of scenarios (baselines) of the same project for what-if analysis
Flexible working hours and leave management
Support for shift working
Multiple time zone support
```

Accounting

```
Tasks may have initial costs, finishing costs
Resources may have usage based costs
Task and/or resource base cost models
Support for profit/loss analysis
```

Reporting

```
Comprehensive and flexible reports so you can find the information you need when you need it
Powerful filtering functions to provide the right amount of detail to the right audience
Time and status sheet reporting infrastructure
Project tracking and status reporting with dashboard support
```

Comment: I was unable to get this working. I installed Ruby and Gem but when running `gem install taskjuggler`, it does not work. This thing needs an installer.

Comment: Sorry, @Thomas, I am not a Ruby person. You can contact the developer at abstractspoon2 AT optusnet DOT com.au as per his page. Beleive me, it will be worth it to get this running :-)

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed. It took me several hours to install and create the initial project, but (under the assumtion that the calculations are correct), TaskJuggler is really awesome. This simple, archivable (SVN) and mergable text file format is what I wanted for a very long time.

Comment: I exported a list of bugs with estimation and priority from Bugzilla and added features. Total ~220 tasks. Add holidays of the team and limits (80% max). Total project planning done in less than an hour. I spent more time for 30 tasks in GanttProject and that did not consider the limits yet, resulting in people being overloaded. It's insane I didn't know TaskJuggler before and I'm glad I took the installation hurdle.

Comment: Just curious, Thomas, are you sill using it?

Comment: From time to time, yes. I'm not doing much project management any more. But in fact, I have even [written a Windows installer](https://github.com/EveryOtherUsernameWasAlreadyTaken/TaskJugglerInstaller) for it. And each of my students must use it at least once ;-)

Comment: Ha ha ha!  Good to know that it is still appreciated - and thanks for the Windows installer. Maybe your students should also look at [ReqView[(https://www.reqview.com/) which  is a reasonable alternative to Doors for requirements management and will let you handle a single small project - up to 150 requirements - for free.