# Lifespan task planner

Tags: windows, project-management

Been looking for an application, a task planner that would store bigger task decomposed to smaller ones. The most obvious way is to respresent tasks as nodes.

Let's say, I want to save some money for a car. I have some options for earning money. Some of them step-by-step. I would like to see my overall progress.

Freeware is preferable, but anything else is ok.

OS: Windows

Comment: @Валя Please [edit] your original question instead of (only) answering in the comments. Also, you don't mention price. Read: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a task planner that would store bigger task decomposed to smaller ones
```

Sounds like classic [Gannt Charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart), so just look for project management software.

Here is a Gannt chart, is this what you are looking for?
[image]

I hear good things about [Open Project](https://www.openproject.org/), but I personally prefer (and have used for years) [Task Juggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/).

It that seems a bit too much for you, then for personal, not software development, porpoises, I use Abstract Spoon's [ToDoList](http://www.abstractspoon.com/tdl_resources.html)  (for more detail, see my answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16786/need-a-simple-software-to-manage-tasks-and-their-prerequisites-with-graphical-ch/16855#16855), which was accepted as the answer).

Comment: wonder if some conditional gantt charts exist or an alternative

Comment: just curious -  what is a "conditional gantt chart"? Can you link to a definition or an example? Thanks

Comment: i mean what is a proper notation to combine task duration idea and conditional switch (if <some condition> do this otherwise do that, like [idef3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF3#IDEF3_process_description_language), perhaps ) so as to track worst and best overall duration of the project.

Answer (score 1):

'Subtask' lets you decompose tasks hierarchically in a mind-map style visualization.
It is free for up to 100 Tasks, then its 7 or 15 € / Month:
https://www.subtask.com/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it in a while (because I find [Trello](http://trello.com) fits my needs better), but Task Coach (downloadable from http://www.taskcoach.org/ and also available as a "portable app" through [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/task_coach_portable)) may also meet your needs. At the time of writing it's free on all but iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Xmind](http://www.xmind.net/) when I work alone on a "big" project to organise it in simple tasks. 
When I am not alone on the project I use [Trello](https://trello.com/) instead because managing concurrent access with the free version of Xmind can be tricky (I don't know about the Pro version).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com). It is a project management software initially, but has a very user friendly interface and lets you manage tasks by drag and drop easily. 
It carries more functionality, but you will not be bothered by that unless you actually need it.

[image]