# What is a good pair of test management system and bug tracker system, that can interact with each other?

Tags: open-source, software-testing, debugging

We are looking for two pieces of software:

- Bug Tracker
- Test Management System

Points that are highly important for us:

- The ability for these two to interact with each other, for example, if test management system finds a bug, it can send it to bug tracker
- They are written in any of JAVA, PHP, C# or Python
- Open source
- Can send email notifications
- Well documented

We have not found any good pair having all the above points. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Update:**

**Bug tracker**: *bugzilla*, it allows us to find out the problems, file them and track the procedure to solve it. It makes the communication a lot easier during the process.

**Important points for us are:**

- It can file the bug
- You can tag it
- You can assign a person or a group to solve and verify it separately.
- It can send email notification
- System is mature and reliable, since it is backed by Mozilla and is actively maintained.
- Authentication is enabled.
- It is open source

**Points we think are not suitable for us:**

- It is written in Perl, that no one among our group knows that. We prefer a system to be in any of PHP, Java, C# or Python
- It cannot have an interface to a good test case management system (as far as I know). We want, if a user is applying a test in test case management system, and it fails, he should be able to file a bug case using the existing data to the bug tracker. I think Bugzilla does not allow this. You find the bug from test case management system, then open bugzilla and file it yourself filling all the details how you tested again.

---

**Test case management system**: *Moztrap*, it allows the QA team to define a set of tests for a particular feature, and you can see how many of them failed or passed. Also you can organize the tests for each version and release.

**Important points for us are:**

- It is in Python
- It is actively maintained and supported by Mozilla
- You can assign a set of tests to a particular release or update.
- You can assign task to team member.
- Authentication is enabled.
- It is open source

**Points we think are not suitable for us:**

- The only point is that it can not interact with Bugzilla as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: What are you expecting from the "test managing system" part? Could it be that [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185) also fits your needs? Matches all the other points.

Comment: @lzzy I updated the question. That might help.

Comment: It *might*, if someone happens to know *Moztrap* (see: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185); "throwing in a name is not sufficient – point out your requirements explicitely"). Following that will increase your chances to good answers – especially from people not knowing *Moztrap* but using one of its alternatives ;)

Comment: @Musa You _might_ :-) use 2 separate SaaS tools that both have a suitable API as well? If you would give GIThub or Bitbucket an in between role here, you would add codemanagement, revision to your integral solution. We need more info indeed.

Comment: @lzzy: Thank you for instructions. I have updated the question. Please let me know if still any thing I need to add more.

Comment: @Henk van Cann: Thank you for instructions. I have updated the question. Please let me know if still any thing I need to add more.

Comment: Is it outside of the scope of your question to also consider integration of other tools, such as project planning & continuous integration?  After all, tests are planned in the project plan and can be run by C.I and bugs found by testing can derail the project plan. This sort of reminds me of an old, more encompassing question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020869/seeking-a-true-tool-chain

Comment: You might want to check JIRA and the [Zephyr for JIRA plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.thed.zephyr.je). (I don't have too much experience with it, we're just evaluating it.)

Comment: JIRA is Zephyr are not open source.

Comment: @Musa: Source of JIRA is available if you buy a license: https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/purchase-licensing#customizationsandprofessionalservices-1 I don't have any information about Zephyr.

Comment: @Musa I think your question is much clearer now. Bitbucket or GITHub could still do the job imo. Although both are SaaS and might not be open source, but they have affordable pricing models for your goal. You could then focus on addressing their api's to connect with other tools. Just thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good pair of software pieces that we found useful are:

[**Mantis Bug Tracker**](https://www.mantisbt.org/) and [**Testlink Test Management System**](http://testlink.org/):

- Written in PHP
- Well documented
- Can send emails
- Authentication enabled
- Open source
- Can interact with each other well

Answer (score 1):

From my several years of experience working in project management, web development and  support queues, I have learned that most companies have a bit different processes for dealing with bug requests and test procedures. Because of that, I would suggest using open source system so that **it can be tweaked as the needs change/evolve**. In particular, I would suggest using **Drupal**, which is quite sophisticated open source system with thousands of modules to extend its core functionality. In fact, the whole Drupal.org community uses Drupal based system for tracking bugs and resolutions. Also, the company I worked for, created own project management system in Drupal and it served us well for several years, allowing for constant tweaks of the functionality as we improved our process.

I would suggest checking [Support Ticketing System](https://www.drupal.org/project/support) and [Project Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/pm) modules (both available freely on drupal.org). It may not be exactly what you are looking for but will give you an idea what can be build in Drupal. A simple system to address most of your needs could be build in Drupal using existing modules like Views, Flag, Workflow, Rules, Comment (core module), Taxonomy (core module) - to mention a few. The beauty of Drupal is that with existing modules, there will be minimal or none code writing to achieve most features you are looking for.

Also, if there are other open source tools that don't "speak" to each other, it is an option to us Drupal as the tool that integrates all the data in one place, using many existing plugins and single sign-ons. In addition, the information about your clients and projects could also be stored in Drupal, as well as logged hours, so that there is no need to constantly push that data back and forth between different systems.