# Issue tracker with multi-criteria sorting (alternative to Google Code)

Tags: issue-tracker

For 7 years my project happily used [Google Code's issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/list), but [Google Code is shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.jp/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html).

I am looking for a replacement issue tracker with:

- Sort issues according to multiple variables. Specifically, there should be a way to configure it so that issues appear to all viewers sorted by Type (Bug, Enhancement) then by Priority (Undecided, Critical, High, Medium, Low), then by Status (New, Accepted, Started, WaitingForFeedback, FixedInDev, Fixed), then by descending bug id.
- User-defined labels (for instance "Gestures", "Usability", "Performance", "Release-2.3", etc)
- Free, preferably SaaS, preferably with no ads, but self-hosting is also acceptable.
- Bulk operations: I can select all issues that have the label "Release-2.3" and the status "FixedInDev", and change their status to "Fixed", without having to do it one-by-one.

Tried but rejected:

- JIRA: Not free
- Github: No sorting feature, unusable for big projects. I actually use Github for another project with 500 issues, it is awful, not being able to sort issues efficiently results in time loss and important issues sometimes getting forgotten. In short, it is bad at issue tracking. Also, the search box first shows matches in source code, requiring an extra click to show results from the issue tracker only, which is a pain when triaging.
- Bitbucket: Same problems as Github.

Comment: Nicolas, remember the other answer you asked me to post today? Please check [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1560/185), take a closer look at the first screenshot there: Click a column to sort by it, and use the "custom query" link in the upper-right for more. "Labels" = "Tags"; free, open-source. Would that match?

Comment: @Izzy: In your screenshot, can you sort first by Type, and then by Status? If yes, that would make a valid answer :-)

Comment: Not natively. That feature [was requested 4 years ago](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/10178), but though the ticket even contains a patch, it was not applied yet. Of course you could do so yourself: "You've got the source, Luke", the tool is written in Python. // According to the Trac Wiki, you should be able to [specify your report using SQL](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Ticketcolumns), which might substitute to a degree. Again, long time that I've played with that.