# Complaint/Incident Resolution System

Tags: windows, project-management

#### Background

I work with the govt. sector. Currently we have a very rudimentary "complaint resolution system"(CRS) which has many drawbacks. Hence many citizens prefer not to log issues on the CRS and instead call the helpdesk. The helpdesk staff takes the calls, make a note on an excel sheet, attach any email citizen may have sent and make a "paper based file" and forward it to IT dept. Thereafter there is no idea on the status of the incident. We from the "business side of the dept" also do not have any mechanism to track where in the IT dept is the ticket and who is currently working on it. No tracking system, no prioritizing of the issues, no accountability !!

We are planning to streamline this incident management mess which is currently there in our department. However, we have constraint of : Budget and the fact that we are part of govt. and hence adopting anything radical will not happen as quickly as we want. Therefore, we were thinking of taking small steps and hence thought of going ahead with a simple yet effective and preferably "open source" system to manage the incident management system in our dept.

#### What we're looking for

Please can you suggest a suitable incident management software(open source) which can help us? I have worked on Quality Centre (QC) of HP and I need similar king of functionality where I get following features:

1. ability to assign incidents to different team members
2. track record with timestamp of various comments on that incident
3. tracking facility of how long the incident has been with a particular individual
4. reporting features - charts and graphs
5. integration with internal DB so that by entering a particular ID no., many pre-stored info, like name, address, etc gets populated in the system
6. Can there be a web-interface also to it, so that citizens can themselves log in their incidents and they be assigned some ticket number which they can use to track their ticket? We dont expect more than 200 incidents logged per day.

I would appreciate your help here.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Free incident management tool for more than 50 users](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1380/185)