# Web app for ticketing

Tags: web-apps, issue-tracker, support-tracker

I need to find a software (possibly free) where users can login, create a ticket to me and see the status of the ticket.

I would like to be automatically notified by email when users create a new ticket. Everyone who has access to the system shall be able to see all the tickets. I would like to be self-hosted.

Comment: This blog post lists some free and open source help desk software solutions: http://blog.capterra.com/the-7-best-free-help-desk-software-tools/

Comment: Most of these should fit your requirements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free incident management tool for more than 50 users](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/free-incident-management-tool-for-more-than-50-users)