# Open-source alternatives to Zendesk?

Tags: open-source, help-desk, support-tracker

I'm looking for an IT-Support help-desk/servicedesk ticket-system. I came across Zendesk. It's nice, but I'm more interested in open-source solution.

Can somebody recommend me some service-desk/help-desk software for 1st/2nd-Level-IT-Support?

Process would likely be like this:

1) Email from User XY comes in with an incident to the HelpDesk at support@company.com

2) User XY gets a standard automated response that the incident has been logged and the ticket has the number 123.

3) Now at the HelpDesk the support employee will categorize the incident and, if necessary, priorities it because there's other tickets awaiting.

4) Ticket from User XY is being handled: Email back and forth between employee and User XY until incident is resolved, ticket closed OR if no solution is possible, escalated to 2nd-Level Support.

Such a ticket system is something I'm looking for. It can either be web-based, i.e. installed on a webserver, or it can be OS based, installed on a Windows OS. Preferably the later. Nice to have would be file/document attachments to said issue.

Edit: I checked [Free incident management tool for more than 50 users](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/free-incident-management-tool-for-more-than-50-users) , and some of these software pretty much do what I need them to do, however I cannot see if these software allow for automatic ticket creation if somebody mails support@company.com

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: I added a sort of process, hope that helps.

Comment: It does indeed. So shall it be web-based, or OS-specific (in the latter case, to what OS)? Any other specific requirements (such as attaching documents/files, referencing code changes etc., report generation, …)?

Comment: Can be both, web-based, or os-specific (windows), preferably the later. Attaching document/files would be nice (so a report or solution can be attached after the issue has been closed). Referencing code changes not necessary, report generation nice plus, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Check [OsTicket](http://osticket.com/),
it is very popular open source support ticket system.
OsTicket is a platform-independent web-based application.

It requires :

- web server (apache or IIS)
- php
- database (MySql/MariaDB)

It is easy to install and do basic configuration. Administration is done trough web interface. It has plenty of option, active community, and is well maintained. Last release is from September 2017.
By default user can create ticket without previous registration, which is configurable to request registration.
Agents are assigned to department, Group and Team. There you can create  Teams for Level 1,2 and 3.

OsTicket allows for automatic ticket creation from email, but not by default. By default, user has to fill the online form to create a new ticket.

Comment: And how does OsTicket fit the requirements listed? Please see [our discussion here about what an answer should contain](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185).

Answer (score 0):

Since you already mentioned the [thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/free-incident-management-tool-for-more-than-50-users/11998#11998) where I was recommending [Eventum](https://github.com/eventum/eventum/wiki), I am not going to paste the same answer here.

However, to add what I didn't touch on in my original answer: based on the [docs](https://github.com/eventum/eventum/wiki/System-Admin%3A-Email-integration), it does seem to cater to your particular need of automatically creating an issue from an email.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeScout](https://freescout.net) seems to be what you are looking for. It is a help desk and shared mailbox at the same time, does exactly what you need. It does send notifications to support agents when new emails come in, when status or assignee changes. It is free and open source, written in PHP.